# Strange PostgreSQL errors when trying to start a rails server on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I want to get a rails application working with PostgreSQL, but something strange is happening.  My friends were able to install PostgreSQL and execute:

```
sudo su
su postgres
createdb development
```

followed by

```
rails server
```

with no bugs. However, when I try to do that, I get a strange error:

```
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord 3.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1151:in `async_exec': PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "reports" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) 

LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"reports"'::regclass
                                    ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
          FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
            ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
         WHERE a.attrelid = '"reports"'::regclass
           AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
         ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Note that "reports" is a model in the application.

For what it's worth, the database.yml file looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: development
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: post
```

(I don't know what pool means, but I have already set my postgres password to be post)

Comment: Do you have any initializers that do anything with your models?

Comment: what do you mean by that? i don't think so

Comment: Sounds like something in your application initialization is trying to use your `Report` class. That SQL is what ActiveRecord's PostgreSQL adapter uses to figure out the structure of a table and the error indicates that you don't have `reports` in your database. When you `rake db:migrate`, you get the same problem; therefore your application initialization is probably at fault as that happens *before* `db:migrate` does anything useful. What plugins are you using? Do you have anything in `config/initializers`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is an interesting idea. I do have some stuff in config/initializers. Should I look for files that reference the Report class?

Comment: Hard to say, the reference to Reports could be hidden behind a search. I have seen ActiveAdmin involved in this sort of problem before but I don't use it so that's just wild speculation.

Comment: The app actually does have ActiveAdmin installed. Do you happen to have a link to a problem like that? I'm going to continue trying to fix this.

Comment: You could try disabling ActiveAdmin, then do your `db:migrate`, then re-enable ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 2):

Have you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: it gives me the same error when i try rake db:migrate -- rake aborted!
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "reports" does not exist....etc

Comment: what about rake db:reset or rake db:drop & rake db:create (warning: you'll lose any data in your local database if you had any!)

Comment: rake db:drop and rake db:create seem to do nothing, as when i run "rake db:reset" it still gives me the rake aborted! error.

Comment: Try naming your database something else in yml file, then run db:create, db:migrate

Comment: that does not seem to be working either. i heard that this might be fixable if i created the reports table manually -- but do you know how i could go about doing that?

Comment: Create a new rails app and try starting over

Comment: This ended up being my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE a.attrelid = '"reports"'::regclass ...` has too many quotes. It should be `WHERE a.attrelid = 'reports'::regclass ...`

Comment: Interesting -- do you know which file this should be in? I'm going to try to correct it

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know RoR. Probably it assumes somehow that 'reports' is a tablename or column name, but in this context it is a string literal.

Comment: The quotes are fine, the SQL in question is ActiveRecord's version of `\d reports` but the table isn't there yet so the cast fails. This is a chicken'n'egg problem in the application initialization phase.